# How to make a 2x2 figure panel with \flashmovie?

Tags: beamer, subfloats

I want to make a figure made of 2x2 subfigures containing different flash movies. The simplest case with one figure does not work because the movie appears in the left margin. Whereas if I use subfigure the two movies appear in the right margin in two different lines. What do I have to do to have them centered in the same line?

Thanks,

Benjamin

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9}
\usepackage{flashmovie}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary figure}}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
{\flashmovie[engine=flv-player,width=160px,height=126px]{movie1.flv}}
\caption{Some caption text here.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\subfigure[subcaption 1]{\centering { \flashmovie[engine=flv-player,loop=1,width=160px,height=126px]{movie1.flv}}}
\subfigure[subcaption 2]{\centering { \flashmovie[engine=flv-player,loop=1,width=160px,height=126px]{movie2.flv}}}
\caption{Some caption text here.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/828), so we can spend more time on debugging and don't have to figure out what packages and options you use.

Comment: Sorry about that. Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flashmovie` package is not well programmed in that it introduces a lot of spurious space which prevents the inserted video boxes from being properly aligned.

Consider using the `media9` package. The lower right video example uses the same video player component `player_flv_maxi.swf` as used by the `flashmovie` package. Here, `cube.mp4` from the `media9` CTAN package is used for demonstration purposes. Replace it with `movie[123].flv` where needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{graphicx,color,subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
%\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{media9}
%\usepackage{flashmovie}
\usepackage{media9}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary figure}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
%\flashmovie[engine=flv-player,width=160px,height=126px]{movie1.flv}
\includemedia[
  width=160px,height=126px,
  addresource=cube.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  transparent,
  flashvars={source=cube.mp4&scaleMode=letterbox}
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\caption{Some caption text here.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[subcaption 1]{\centering{%
%\flashmovie[engine=flv-player,loop=1,width=160px,height=126px]{movie2.flv}
\includemedia[
  width=160px,height=126px,
  addresource=cube.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  transparent,
  flashvars={source=cube.mp4&loop=true&scaleMode=letterbox}
]{}{VPlayer.swf}%
}}
\subfigure[subcaption 2]{\centering{%
%\flashmovie[engine=flv-player,loop=1,width=160px,height=126px]{movie3.flv}
\includemedia[
  width=160px,height=126px,
  addresource=cube.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  flashvars={
    flv=cube.mp4
   &margin=0
   &showvolume=1
   &showstop=1
   &showtime=1
   &videobgcolor=0xFFFFFF
   &loop=1
  }
]{}{player_flv_maxi.swf}%
}}
\caption{Some caption text here.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```